# How to setup Nginx as smtp proxy to external smtp server?

Tags: email, nginx, proxy, smtp

I am trying to setup nginx mail proxy Gmail smtp server. Nginx server runs on docker.

During tests, I use `openssl s_client -connect mail.localhost.com:12465 -starttls smtp` (ports are different from config for port availability reasons).

Openssl connects successfully and I manage to get EHLO and run AUTH LOGIN. Still, I receive error `502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. u6sm12628547ejn.14 - gsmtp`. Same message appears when `less secure apps` security is on in account.

Running command above directly to smpt.gmail.com works great, and error is displayed correctly if `less secure apps` security is not allowed.

Current nginx.conf is below.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 9101;
        server_name localhost;

        location /smtpauthssl {
            if ($http_auth_user ~* "(?<=@)(\S+$)" ) {
                set $domain $1;
            }
            set $smtp_port '587';
            add_header Auth-Status "OK";
            add_header Auth-Port $smtp_port;
            add_header Auth-Server "108.177.119.108";
            return 200;

        }
        location = / {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}

mail {
    server_name mail.mydomain.com;
    auth_http localhost:9101/smtpauthssl;

    proxy_pass_error_message on;
    proxy_smtp_auth on;
    xclient on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server {
        listen 587 ssl;
        protocol smtp;
        smtp_auth login plain cram-md5;
    }
}
```

My assumption is that something with logon is not passed to Gmail SMTP, but not sure what.

One more thing, what does Auth-Server header should contain, FQDN or IP address?